# (e1 e2 e3) to (m1 m2 m3) using only map and/or apply (Scheme)

Tags: scheme

It should be a basic question in Scheme but I cannot see how to do it o_o

I have a list (e1 e2 e3) and a function m .
What I want is ,using only map and/or apply, get the list (m1 m2 m3), where the notation mN is (m eN) .

My function m isn't unary (it takes the list as first arg and a number as second arg, this number will be applied to the list) and I don't know how to pass a second argument using apply or map .

How can I do this ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but aren't you just describing what `(map m list-of-es)` does?

Comment: Indeed I forgot to say omething : my function m isn't unary (it takes the list as first arg and a number as second arg, this number will be applied to the list) and I don't know how to pass a second argument using apply or map.

Comment: `map` can also take multiple lists, in which case the function is called with one element from each list: `(map + '(5 3 1) '(8 5 3)) => (13 8 4)`.

Comment: `(m eN)` will simply cause a "not enough arguments" error, for a non-unary `m`. please describe your problem in concrete terms, with concrete code, otherwise this is impossible to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but it seems that the second argument to your function must be constant in the context of application:

```
(define lst '(1 2 3))
(define elst '(2 0 1))
(map (lambda (x) (list-ref lst x)) elst)
```

Answer (score 3):

To make this concrete, let's assume *m* is the function that negates an integer, so

```
(define (m n) (- n))
```

For instance, `(m 3)` evaluates to -3. Then you can apply *m* to each element of the list `(1 -2 3)` like this:

```
(map m '(1 -2 3))
```

which will evaluate to the list `(-1 2 -3)`. You can see this in action at http://ideone.com/Le7PHC.

**EDIT:** In a comment, the original poster says his function *m* is binary, not unary. I'm a bit confused, but let me try again and see if this works.

Let's assume that the desired function takes a list of integers as its first argument and an integer as its second argument and returns a new list in which each element of the first list is incremented by the amount of the second argument; thus, the function might take the list `(1 3 5)` and the integer 7 and return the list `(8 10 12)`. This function does that:

```
(define (f xs n)
  (map (lambda (x) (+ x n))
       xs))
```

You can see that at http://ideone.com/KmcSef.

I hope this answers your question. If not, please give a more concrete example, including specific input and output, of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I understand this totally, but I think I forgot something, sorry x) my function m isn't unary ; it takes two args : the list I want to apply some number (the number is the second arg)